# I'm not able to cover the handler being executed while writing test cases using Jasmine Karma

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am new in writing test cases using Jasmine and Karma.

This is the piece of code I'm trying to cover.

```
oncreate: () => addWindowResizeListener(() => this._resizeHandler())
```

Below is the line referring to the above in my spec file

```
expect(contentPanelFooterBodyVDOM.getAttr("oncreate")).toEqual(Function)
```

The code coverage is shown as below

How can I attain complete code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code coverage but you have to actually call your function to get code coverage.

```
// spy on the function to be called.
spyOn(something, '_resizeHandler');
// call the function
something.oncreate();
// expect for it to be called
expect(something._resizeHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I'm unable to attach the code coverage image as I do not have enough points. However, I'm able to cover until the addWindowResizeListener. I'm not able to cover the inner function this._resizeHandler(). Hope this gives more information. I tried the above solution but the issue remains. Please Help.

Comment: I am guessing `addWindowResizeListener` gets invoked when the window gets resized. Maybe after `something.oncreate()`, resize the window.